# Jackson 2.0 Serialization config in writeValue method

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Currently we are using Jackson 1.9.x in our application and have following code:

```
  Object objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  .....
  SerializationConfig config = getConfig();
  objectMapper.writeValue(jg, value, config);
```

As I understand during investigation (see [SerializationConfig](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig.html)) in Jackson 2.0 (de)serialziation was changed and cannot be attached directly to objectMapper and my question is: What is correct replacment for the last sentence in code snippet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would create an `ObjectWriter`, and reconfigure that if necessary:

```
ObjectWriter w = mapper.writer(....); // various configuration methods
w.writeValue(jg, value);
```

Underlying configuration objects are hidden on purpose, as `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter` are immutable and thread-safe, so you can share and pass those instead of config objects.